# Unmatched route angularjs (ui-router)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, .htaccess, angular-ui-router

I wrote in my app.js file this line of code:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/view1');
```

This is my htaccess file:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
</ifModule>
```

Now, if I try to run myrul/invented_route the response's server is "Not found" even if the otherwise route is setted.

Comment: I am not sure but it must be like $urlRouterProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo:'/view1'});

Comment: I think the problem is another one because the app didn't run if I type one invented route, it s like the htacess doesn't work! You know what I mean?

Comment: sorry, but are you sure that mod_rewrite module is enabled? because I used the same .htaccess as you did but its work

Comment: Angular routes works only on the client!

Comment: No it doesn't work! If I type myurl/route1 (route1 is known) it doesn't work as well. What should I do?

Comment: is html5mode enabled? Information provided is very thin

Comment: Yes it is, but I have just discovered the htaccess is not enabled. I will enable in a while and I will text again